# predecessor and multiplication prove

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, theorem-provers

I have trouble, when attempting to :

1- prove mult defines the multiplication function.

2- Prove pred defines the predecessor function.

1- for mult:

Base Case:

mult 0x= 0

Inductive case:

:= $(\lambda m. \lambda n. \lambda f . \lambda x.m (nf)x) (\lambda f. \lambda x.x)(\lambda fx. \lambda x.(f^{(n)} x))$

the result is  $(\lambda f. \lambda x.x)$.

2- for pred:

Base Case:

f(0,..)= 0

Inductive case:

$\lambda n.\lambda f. \lambda x.n (\lambda g. \lambda h.h (gf)) (\lambda u.x)( \lambda u.u)$.

(f(s(x),..) = n-1

And I am unsure of where to go from there, because I have no parameters for the n to be n-1.

Comment: The fact that $(λm.λn.λ f .λx.m (nf)x) (λf. λx.x)(λfx.λx.(f^{(n)} x))$ reduces to $(λf. λx.x)$ proves that $\text{mult} \, 0 \, n = 0$. The inductive case for $\text{mult}$ is completely lacking.

Comment: what about predecessor ?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I have been create post for multiplication question.

Comment: please answer the second part here: I asked it as a new question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841777/multiplication-prove-in-lambda-calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that the term $\text{pred}$ encodes the predecessor function over natural numbers is quite technical and requires a lemma.

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\underline{n} = \lambda f \lambda x. f^{n} x = \lambda f \lambda x. \overbrace{f (\cdots (f}^{n \text{ times}} x) \cdots)$ (in particular, $\underline{0} = \lambda f \lambda x.x$).

*Lemma.* Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+1} (\lambda u.x)$ reduces to $\lambda h.h (f^n x)$

*Proof.* By induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

- Base case ($n = 0$):

\begin{align}
(\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda u.x) \to \lambda h.h ((\lambda u.x) f) \to \lambda h.h x \,.
\end{align}

- Inductive step: we suppose that $(\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+1} (\lambda u.x)$ reduces to $\lambda h.h (f^n x) \, $ (induction hypothesis) and we show that $(\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+2} (\lambda u.x)$ reduces to $\lambda h.h (f^{n+1} x)$.

\begin{align}
(\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+2} (\lambda u.x) &= (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) \big((\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+1} (\lambda u.x) \big) \\
&\to^* (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda h.h (f^n x)) \quad \text{(by induction hypothesis)} \\
& \to  \lambda h.h ((\lambda h.h (f^nx)) f) \to \lambda h.h (f (f^n x)) = \lambda h.h (f^{n+1} x) \, .\\ &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \square 
\end{align}

Let $\text{pred} = \lambda n \lambda f \lambda x.n (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u)$.
Thanks to the lemma above, let us show that the term $\text{pred}$ encodes the predecessor function over natural numbers, *i.e.* that $\text{pred} \, \underline{0}$ reduces to $\underline{0}$, and $\text{pred} \, \underline{n+1}$ reduces to $\underline{n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

- Case $n = 0$: 
  \begin{align}
   \text{pred} \, \underline{0} =& \ \big(\lambda n \lambda f \lambda x.n (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \big) \lambda f \lambda x.x \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda f' \lambda x'.x') (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda x'.x') (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. x = \underline{0} 
  \end{align}
- Case $n + 1$:
  \begin{align}
   \text{pred} \, \underline{n+1} =& \ \big(\lambda n \lambda f \lambda x.n (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \big) \lambda f \lambda x. f^{n+1}x \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda f' \lambda x'. (f')^{n+1}x') (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f)) (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda x'. (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+1} x') (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda g \lambda h.h (g f))^{n+1} (\lambda u.x) (\lambda u.u) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda h. h (f^n x)) (\lambda u.u) \quad \text{(by the lemma)}\\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. (\lambda u.u) (f^n x) \\
  \to& \ \lambda f \lambda x. f^n x = \underline{n} \, .
  \end{align}

---

The proof that the term $\text{mult}$ encodes the multiplication function over natural numbers is similar to (and slightly simpler than) the proof above.

Comment: Thanks. but for mult do I need to have exponential ?

Comment: @Jared - Yes, but I guess a complete answer for $\text{mult}$ requires a new question, otherwise this answer becomes too long.

Comment: Ok , I will post it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089352/multiplication-prove